# What makes cart with a moving object in it gain speed (no friction anywhere)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, momentum, friction

I would like to understand what makes the cart below the moving object move. 
There is no friction between any of the objects.
The cart is moving therefore there is force applied to it.
The only force can come from the small object.
However, the small object has only mg and normal force acting on it, and mg has no component in the cart moving speed, and normal force has component in the opposite direction, so what makes it move?

Conservation of momentum? But it is not a force.

[image]

Comment: Conservation of momentum is guaranteed by Newton's third law, which is?

Comment: Draw a free body diagram for the cart.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Normal force braek down]The small object exerts a force in the opposite direction to the normal force on the cart